# T-SQL Drop multiiple constraints if exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints, ssms

How can I apply this for multiple constraints from different tables:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('DF_Constraint') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tableName]
    DROP CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint
END
```

didn't work for me like this:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('DF_Constraint') IS NOT NULL)
AND (OBJECT_ID('DF_Constraint2') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tableName] DROP CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint;
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tableName2] DROP CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint2;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('DF_Constraint') IS NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tableName] DROP CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint;

IF OBJECT_ID('DF_Constraint2') IS NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tableName2] DROP CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint2;
```

This way you can delete each constraint if it exists (you don't need to have both constraints to delete each one).

Comment: just without the BEGIN.... END then. So it s mandatory to separate them so it ll not be treated only at the existence of both, alright, Thank You*